# Powershell Async

Tags: wpf, powershell, user-interface

i am working with powershell and wpf to build a gui. I want to change the content of a button while runtime of the tool. But it got changed when the other commands are finished. I tried to start the command as job because i read that powershell works synchronously. Even if the command to change the content is in the first position

Following my Code:

```
try {
        $btnCreateUser1.Content = "Bitte warten..."
        $oldinformationJob = Invoke-Command -AsJob -ComputerName test -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Get-Aduser -identity $using:ReferenceUserTextBox.Text -Properties * -Credential $Using:cred}
        $oldinformation = Wait-Job $oldinformationJob | Receive-Job
        $Passwort = 'test'
        $Attributes = @{
            SAMAccountname = $NewUserUsernameTextBox.Text
            UserPrincipalName = "$($NewUserUsernameTextBox.Text)@test.de"
            Name = "$($FirstNameTextBox.Text) $($LastNameTextBox.Text)"
            AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString $Passwort -AsPlainText -Force)
            Path = ($oldinformation.DistinguishedName).Split(",",2)[1]
            GivenName = $FirstNameTextBox.Text
            Surname = $LastNameTextBox.text
            Enabled =$true
            DisplayName = "$($LastNameTextBox.Text), $($FirstNameTextBox.Text)"
            City = ""
            PostalCode = ""
            Country = ""
            State = ""
            Company = $oldinformation.company
            StreetAddress = $oldinformation.StreetAddress
            OfficePhone = $NummerTextBox.text
            Department = $oldinformation.Department
            Office = $RaumTextBox.Text
            Title = $PositionBox.Text
            HomeDirectory = "\\test\user\Home\$($NewUserUsernameTextBox.Text)"
            Homedrive = "U"
        }
        
        Invoke-Command -AsJob -ComputerName test -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
            New-ADUser @Using:Attributes -Credential $Using:cred
        }
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        Invoke-Command -AsJob -ComputerName test -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $($Using:oldinformation.SAMAccountname) -ResourceContextServer "test" -Credential $Using:cred | ForEach-Object {Add-ADGroupmember -Identity $_.SAMAccountname  -Members $($Using:Attributes.SAMAccountname) -Credential $Using:cred -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}} 
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Der User $($NewUserUsernameTextBox.Text) wurde erstellt ","Active Directory Tool",0)
        $btnCreateUser1.Content = "Benutzer erstellen"
```

Comment: Check out the blog of fellow SO user @foxdeploy, he has multiple articles regarding this topic (which should still be up to date). https://www.foxdeploy.com/series/LearningGUIs

Answer (score 0):

See: [Using Dispatcher Invoke with a Runspace in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440599/using-dispatcher-invoke-with-a-runspace-in-powershell)

WPF controls, like the button in your script, can only be updated from the UI thread. If you’re trying to update a control from a different thread (like a job thread), you’ll need to use the `Dispatcher.Invoke` method to marshal the call to the UI thread.

```
$btnCreateUser1.Dispatcher.Invoke({
    $btnCreateUser1.Content = "Bitte warten..."
}, [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority]::Background)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Added reference.